# Cannot convert MySQL Table from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am trying to convert a MySQL Table from MyISAM to InnoDB.

I use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_wpr_rucss_used_css` ENGINE=InnoDB
```

But get the following error:

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'modified'
```

Why? How to solve it?

**Update**

I run the following command

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `wp_wpr_rucss_used_css`
```

and

get the following result:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_wpr_rucss_used_css` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `url` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `css` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
 `unprocessedcss` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `retries` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `is_mobile` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `last_accessed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `url` (`url`(150),`is_mobile`),
 KEY `modified` (`modified`),
 KEY `last_accessed` (`last_accessed`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: add schema definition of table **wp_wpr_rucss_used_css** and output of  **show variables like 'sql_mode' ; **

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before the ALTER.

Comment: @RickJames, I have add the result of "Show Create Table" in the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you have **0000-00-00 00:00:00** as the default value So
generally, The problem is because of sql_modes. Please check your current **sql_modes** by command:

`show variables like 'sql_mode';`

remove the sql_mode **"NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE"** if you have. Then run your alter command.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my question.